# Having a hard time on figuring out how to move my snake constantly

Tags: java, std, jgrasp

So I'm creating a java game called snake, I'm currently stuck on how to get the start of the snake to constantly moved after it is initially moved, Im trying to use the thread.sleep but I'm pretty use I'm using it in the wrong place any tips/help would be appreciated!

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
public class snake
{
   static double squareX = .5;
   static double squareY = .5;
   static double squareR = .02;
   static double CsquareR = .01;
   static double CsquareX = Math.random();
   static double CsquareY = Math.random();




   public static void drawScene() 
   {
      StdDraw.clear();
      StdDraw.filledSquare(squareX, squareY, squareR);
      StdDraw.filledSquare(CsquareX, CsquareY, CsquareR);
      StdDraw.show(1000/24);  
   }




   public static void updateMotion() throws InterruptedException
   {

      if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_UP))
      {
         squareY += .01;
         Thread.sleep(10);
      }
      else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
      {
         squareY -= .01;
         Thread.sleep(10);
      }
      else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT))
      {
         squareX -= .01;
         Thread.sleep(10);
      }
      else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT))
      {
         squareX += .01;
         Thread.sleep(10);
      }
   }



   public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException 
   {
       while(true)
       {
         snake.drawScene();
         snake.updateMotion();
         if (squareX + squareR >= 1 )
         {
            //TODO: show "you lose" message / stop on edge of square
            break;
         }
         if (squareX - squareR <= 0)
         {
            //TODO: show "you win" message / stop on edge of square
            break;
         }   
         if (squareY + squareR >= 1 )
         {
            //TODO: show "you lose" message / stop on edge of square
            break;
         }
         if (squareY - squareR <= 0)
         {
            //TODO: show "you win" message / stop on edge of square
            break;
         }    
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What means "constantly"? `sleep` merely adds a pause, the snake should move without that (albeit very very fast)

Comment: Like when you press down it keeps going down until you hit another key or hits the wall, meaning it won't stop moving once you hit the first key

Comment: store & update the direction the snake needs to go and then increment the position in that direction regardless of any `isKeyPressed` status

Comment: You need a single "game-loop" which is responsible for updating the state of the game and schedule updates to the UI

Comment: What do you mean by game-loop. Like for updating the snakes length and the cherry?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the position *while* the keys are pressed, change the direction and update the position all the time.

```
   static double xMovement = 0;
   static double yMovement = 0;

   public static void updatePosition() {
       squareX += xMovement;
       squareY += yMovement;
   }

   public static void updateDirection() throws InterruptedException
   {

      if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_UP))
      {
          xMovement =  0.0;
          yMovement = +0.1;
      }
      else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
      {
          xMovement =  0.0;
          yMovement = -0.1;
      }
      else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT))
      {
          xMovement = -0.1;
          yMovement =  0.0;
      }
      else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT))
      {
          xMovement = +0.1;
          yMovement =  0.0;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException 
   {
       while(true)
       {
         snake.drawScene();
         snake.updateDirection();
         snake.updatePosition();
...
```